# How can I visualize every change in a long line in a new line with git with less context?

Tags: git, powershell

I have a file with a very long line (325357 characters) that has word-wise changes that I want to visualize. So imagine something like:

> Befor: Lorem ipsum dolor change1befor sit amet, consectetur change2befor *really long text* change3befor adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. [...]

> After: Lorem ipsum dolor change1after sit amet, consectetur change2after *really long text* change3after adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. [...]

I want to see every change on a new line, with only little context (maybe 5 characters). I am using git on Windows (and would be fine with a solution for PowerShell or if not possible also GitBASH)

The best I could get so far was using `git diff --word-diff .\old.txt .\new.txt`

This results in:
[image]
But please imagine `*really long text*` is 5000 characters long, then it becomes really hard to read.

Comment: " 5000 characters long, then it becomes really hard to read." I think you say all here, diff is hard to read because the source is hard to read. diff so fancy can help:  https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use some tools to compare them.such as `VS code` or `IntelliJ IDEA`.
They can show the differeces side by side and line by line.

Comment: The problem is, that a line by line diff does not solve my problem. I have a line by line diff with git diff, but as there are small changes inside this line, it is basically useless.

Comment: VS Code (with the Git Lens extension) provides color highlighting for every change at every character that is different.